# Grails 2.0.4 stops serving certain images randomly in an AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment

Tags: image, grails, resources, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm having an odd 'showstopper' problem that I can't reproduce locally or hosting in a standalone Tomcat 7 environment.

For some reason, certain images just stop being served after a random amount of time.  There doesn't seem to be any pattern to it.  Both absolute and relative path images are affected.  And, very interestingly, the links to the 'broken' ones actually start getting rendered differently in the GSP, which makes me think that internally Grails isn't seeing them either:

```
 <img src="${resource(dir: 'images/brochure', file: 'slide_01.png')}" alt=""/>
This is a broken one, and results in
 <img src="/images/brochure/slide_01.png" alt=""/>
on the rendered GSP


<img src="${resource(dir: 'images/brochure', file: 'slide_02.png')}" alt=""/>
This one works, and results in 
<img src="/static/images/brochure/slide_02.png" alt=""/>
on the rendered GSP
```

Note that even if I manually add back the /static/ it is still broken.  The images definitely exist, and if I restart the app, everything works again for a while.  And it isn't always the same images that deteriorate

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!  I have a feeling the 'resources' plugin is doing something odd, but I have no idea what, or how to fix it.

I'm using two instances with sticky sessions running Tomcat 7