# Grails 2.1.4 and 2.0.4 stops serving random JS and CSS files in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: grails, amazon-web-services, grails-plugin, grails-2.0, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a big problem with our Grails application running in AWS Elastic Beanstalk.
Our application is running on 4 instances with Tomcat 7 and sometimes it scales to more.
From time to time a random instance (1 out of 4) stops serving some JavaScript or css files.
When I manually try to hit the URL with /js/my_script.js or /static/js/my_script.js it responds with 404. The only way to fix it is to restart the application servers. I also noticed that sometimes it happens after the environment scales.
Here is the code which I use to load the resources:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir: 'js', file: 'my_script.js')}"></script>
```

I could not reproduce this in my local environment.
I found a very similar question which didn't get answered:
[Grails 2.0.4 stops serving certain images randomly in an AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11514658/2292199)

Another fact which might be relevant to this is that Elastic Beanstalk's default Session Stickiness is enabled for this environment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to use resources:1.2.RC2?

Comment: I haven't tried resources:1.2.RC2, is it stable enough for production environments?

Comment: I don't have issues with that, but I cannot guarantee that's safe. Diggin a little in the JIRA I found a comment that may be helpfull to you: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPRESOURCES-157. Did you defined the work dir? Maybe, as Marc says, your files are being deleted.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sergio, I'll take a look at this and will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [Sérgio Michels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/800014/sergio-michels) should be right. The resource plugin has a bug and it was solved in that release, but it's only a RC not a final version.

For me worked, but i was not using AWS, see the post below:

[Grails: Images / CSS missing from time to time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432521/grails-images-css-missing-from-time-to-time/15174643#15174643)